# Centos nginx + django + gunicorn 403 forbidden

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, gunicorn

I have  a centos server with nginx installed where i would to load a django app.
After install python34, nginx, django and gunicorn i configure nginx.conf file like this:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

index   index.html index.htm;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  54.17X.2XX.11X;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

location /static/ {
    #alias /opt/cath/static/;
    alias /home/ec2-user/test/endpoint/website/static/;
} 

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/site;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
```

well at this point, when i start gunicorn and nginx seervic for all the resource under /home/ec2-user/test/endpoint/website/static/ i receive the 403 forbidden access error.
I try with:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 <Path to static>
```

also tried with

```
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx <path to static>
```

but error 403 persist

How can i resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

but the problem persist

Comment: Did you restarted nginx  server after updating permissions ?

Comment: yes i did sudo service nginx restart

Comment: `/home/ec2-user/test/endpoint/website/static/` is not a good place to keep your stuff. The issue is that even if you give permission to a child level folder and the parent is not accessible then the access would be denied. Also check which user nginx is using. run `ps aux | grep nginx` and see the user for the worker process, you need to use that user for the access. `777` permission is a real bad idea as such. Also if you are on centos then see if selinux is enabled, try disabling that

Comment: Could you please put the output from the error log of nginx

Comment: Did you try `sudo chown -R :www-data <path to static>` ?

Answer (score 0):

i think it is related to SELinux you can disable it by:

nano /etc/selinux/config
change the value of SELINUX to disabled

Answer (score 0):

`location / { include proxy_params; proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock; }`